# StreamReader fails with wrong directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load a file from my web application's App_Data folder:

```
  KezMenu kmenu = new KezMenu("~/App_Data/Menu.xml");
```

But for some reason, this causes MSVC to try to find it in a weird area:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\App_Data\Menu.xml'.
```

I don't understand why it points here rather than my project directory.

What must I do to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like `KezMenu` is expecting *you* (rather than it) to worry about virtual vs physical paths. Try:

```
KezMenu kmenu = new KezMenu(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Menu.xml"));
```

or

```
KezMenu kmenu = new KezMenu(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Menu.xml"));
```

if you already have a `Server` property available.